# redux saga cannot read property getState of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to set up a react redux store with saga middleware and async actions, as well as react-router-redux and selectors.

For some the sagamiddleware cannot read property getState of undefined. I don't know why.

my top level dir structure is:

```
./src/app.js
./src/sagas/index.js and imported sagas into this file
./src/Containers/App/actions.js constants.js appReducer.js selectors.js
./src/Containers/App/toplevelcomponenthere
```

app.js

```
import sagas from './sagas';
import createReducer from './reducers.js';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxRouterMiddleware,
sagaMiddleware(...sagas))(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(createReducer);
const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory)

//add selectors and history
import { selectLocationState } from './Containers/App/selectors';
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: selectLocationState(),
});

class Base extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    {children}
    </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add the code with the `getState`

Comment: @KevinKloet getState breaks internally inside of redux-saga see here
https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/4ec433410c60eb1675ae786181651454fe766ddd/dist/redux-saga.js
line of code 1898

Answer (score 0):

you apply saga middleware wrong way. Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/store/configureStore.prod.js) `sagaMiddlewate` doesn't take any arguments.

You have to pass your `root saga` to `store.runSaga` function after you create a store,  like [here](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/index.js). And that's root saga - single function which will for example `fork` other sagas you want to use. I think your `sagas` imported from `./sagas` not a single function since you have applied a spread operator to it.